# How do I upgrade drush?

Tags: ubuntu, drush

I created a drupal site in AWS on a ubuntu machine.  I have used

```
sudo apt-get drush
```

to download the newest drush version, version 7.

when I use

```
drush version
```

I still get version 5.10.0

Now that i have that i am still using drush version 5.  how do I make it use drush version 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drush 7 uses composer and should be installed with:
`composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`

If you don't have composer installed: 
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`